# How can I run the spell checker on a text area instantly?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Often, when editing questions on Super User for example, I see an obvious spelling error. Yet, when I edit the question, it looks like everything is fine:

[image]

But once I *stepped* through (holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>) the whole text, the spelling errors are marked red:

[image]

How can I have all spelling errors marked red **instantly**?

Comment: Does CTRL+A, CTRL+RIGHT, CTRL+LEFT and then UP work (this should "emulate" going through the entire text with CTRL+RIGHT)? It really seems to be no keyboard shortcut to start the spell check in Chrome.

Comment: @TeXHeX: Doesn't work here

Answer (score 1):

Select all the text (Ctrl+A), cut it, then re-paste it.  All the words that need correction should be highlighted at once.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The pasted text doesn't show any red underlines until I step through it once more.

Comment: Weird.  What OS and browser are you using?  It worked for me in Firefox v14 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm asking about Chrome :)

Comment: Ah, I see that in the tags now.  Missed it before.  I tried it in Chrome and got the same behavior you described.  Maybe I should change my answer to "use Firefox"? ;)